# Grouping words by their differences

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, gathering

I'm a new guy here and I face a problem. I should pair the following words according to the rule: pair the words, that differ by max. 2  characters, like:

`{chocolate, chocolates, thocolates}` or `{fox, nox, box}`:

The list to apply this rule to is:

```
horse, horses, morse, morses, norse, norses, fox, monses, goose, tool, goal, tools, gothe
```

I had an idea with `EditDistance`, but I can compare the words with only using a sample (e.g. comparing `fox` with the other words), but it seemed not good...

Thanks your help!

---

One more thing: one word can appear not only once in the list, beceause one word can differ from more than one word...

Comment: Uh, one other thing, that on the list max 2 are being paired, like chocolates, thocolates or nox, box

Comment: It seems we have 3 interpretations, could you say who has understood you well?

Comment: If you only need the pairs of such words you can directly Select them `Select[Tuples[words, 2], EditDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] <= 2 &]`

Answer (score 6):

```
words = {"horse", "horses", "morse", "morses", "norse", "norses", 
  "fox", "monses", "goose", "tool", "goal", "tools", "gothe"}
```

I'm not very experienced with Graphs so any advice, how to make it shorter, is welcome.

```
adjacencyMatrix = Outer[
  Boole@LessEqual[1, #, 2] &@*EditDistance,
  words,
  words
];

adjacencyGraph = AdjacencyGraph[words, adjacencyMatrix];
```

**Edit:**

So we have 3 interpretations, let's deal with them all.

1. Subsets of words where all elements are at most 2 `EditDistance` from each other:

   ```
   cliques = FindClique[ adjacencyGraph, Infinity, All ]
   ```

   > ```
   > {{"horse", "horses", "morse", "morses", "norse", "norses"}, 
   > {"horses", "morse", "morses", "norses", "monses"}, 
   > {"horse", "morse", "norse", "goose"},
   > {"goose", "gothe"}, 
   > {"tool", "tools"}, 
   > {"tool", "goal"}, 
   > {"fox"}}
   > ```
2. Pairs of words that differ at most 2 `EditDistance` from each other:

   ```
   List @@@ EdgeList@adjacencyGraph
   ```

   > ```
   > {{"horse", "horses"}, {"horse", "morse"}, {"horse", "morses"}, 
   > {"horse", "norse"}, {"horse", "norses"}, {"horse", "goose"}, 
   > {"horses", "morse"}, {"horses", "morses"}, {"horses", "norse"}, 
   > {"horses", "norses"}, {"horses", "monses"}, {"morse", "morses"},
   > {"morse", "norse"}, {"morse", "norses"}, {"morse", "monses"}, 
   > {"morse", "goose"}, {"morses", "norse"}, {"morses", "norses"},
   > {"morses", "monses"}, {"norse", "norses"}, {"norse", "goose"},
   > {"norses", "monses"}, {"goose", "gothe"}, {"tool", "goal"}, 
   > {"tool", "tools"}}
   > ```
3. Subsets of words where all elements differ from given word by at most 2 `EditDistance`:

   ```
   # -> VertexComponent[adjacencyGraph, #, 1] & /@ VertexList[adjacencyGraph]
   ```

> ```
> {"horse" -> {"horse", "horses", "morse", "morses", "norse", "norses", 
>    "goose"}, 
>  "horses" -> {"horses", "horse", "morse", "morses", "norse", "norses",
>     "monses"}, 
>  "morse" -> {"morse", "horse", "horses", "morses", "norse", "norses", 
>    "monses", "goose"}, 
>  "morses" -> {"morses", "horse", "horses", "morse", "norse", "norses",
>     "monses"}, 
>  "norse" -> {"norse", "horse", "horses", "morse", "morses", "norses", 
>    "goose"}, 
>  "norses" -> {"norses", "horse", "horses", "morse", "morses", "norse",
>     "monses"}, "fox" -> {"fox"}, 
>  "monses" -> {"monses", "horses", "morse", "morses", "norses"}, 
>  "goose" -> {"goose", "horse", "morse", "norse", "gothe"}, 
>  "tool" -> {"tool", "goal", "tools"}, "goal" -> {"goal", "tool"}, 
>  "tools" -> {"tools", "tool"}, "gothe" -> {"gothe", "goose"}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
selector[str_String] :=
 GroupBy[list, EditDistance[str, #] <= 2 &][True] /.
  str -> Style[str, Red, Bold]

list = {"horse", "horses", "morse", "morses", "norse", "norses", 
   "fox", "monses", "goose", "tool", "goal", "tools", "gothe"};

selector /@ list
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
selector2[str_String] :=
 Thread[str -> GroupBy[list, 0 < EditDistance[str, #] <= 2 &][True]]

Flatten[selector2 /@ list] /. Missing[__] :> {}

(*  {"horse" -> "horses", "horse" -> "morse", "horse" -> "morses", 
 "horse" -> "norse", "horse" -> "norses", "horse" -> "goose", 
 "horses" -> "horse", "horses" -> "morse", "horses" -> "morses", 
 "horses" -> "norse", "horses" -> "norses", "horses" -> "monses", 
 "morse" -> "horse", "morse" -> "horses", "morse" -> "morses", 
 "morse" -> "norse", "morse" -> "norses", "morse" -> "monses", 
 "morse" -> "goose", "morses" -> "horse", "morses" -> "horses", 
 "morses" -> "morse", "morses" -> "norse", "morses" -> "norses", 
 "morses" -> "monses", "norse" -> "horse", "norse" -> "horses", 
 "norse" -> "morse", "norse" -> "morses", "norse" -> "norses", 
 "norse" -> "goose", "norses" -> "horse", "norses" -> "horses", 
 "norses" -> "morse", "norses" -> "morses", "norses" -> "norse", 
 "norses" -> "monses", "fox" -> {}, "monses" -> "horses", "monses" -> "morse",
  "monses" -> "morses", "monses" -> "norses", "goose" -> "horse", 
 "goose" -> "morse", "goose" -> "norse", "goose" -> "gothe", "tool" -> "goal",
  "tool" -> "tools", "goal" -> "tool", "tools" -> "tool", "gothe" -> "goose"}  *)
```

Comment: @Kuba - I am confused by the wording of the question; however, my approach groups all words within `EditDistance` of 2 from the base (Red) word. Each word is taken as the starting base.

Comment: My bad, I even changed the wording in my edit. I would think that @Kuba is right, because the originator also wondered about having to compare with one word only.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
  {"horse", "horses", "morse", "morses", "norse", "norses", 
     "fox", "monses", "goose", "tool", "goal", "tools", "gothe"};

char = Characters /@ Subsets[list, {2}];

rev = Reverse /@ (SortBy[#, Length] & /@ char);

com = Complement @@@ rev;

pos = Position[com, a_List /; Length@a <= 2]; 

Map[StringJoin, Extract[rev, pos], {2}] // Sort // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: I'd say that `fox` and `tool` differ by 3 characters. p.s. you have a typo aster `pos` line.

Comment: Good point - I was thinking fox - o = fx = 2 chars difference. But with this logic all one and two letter words would qualify.